# Emulator crashes and phone isn't recognized on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I never had problems using Android Studio, while debugging directly on device or via emulator. Today after a long time, i tried to install it on my workstation and it looks like there are unidentified problems, that I didn't find anywhere on google ...

---

Emulator:

I tried 981234912849821 different settings but i can't start an emulation, it worked only ONE time. When i opened it again, it didn't work again D:

The emulator always starts, then crashes saying:

> qemu-system-i386.exe has stopped working

I tried to use it with `Graphics: Software - GLES 2.0` and this is the result:

[image]

---

I became bored about it, so i tried to directly use my phone and i discovered that android studio wasn't finding it, even by changing type of usb connection ...

---

Do you have any idea about this problem guys? ^^

PS: Don't flag it as duplicate, I already saw the answers on who has these problems but nothing worked for me :\

Answer (score 0):

You need an ADB driver for your phone installed on your system. Also make sure that under the Developer Settings in Settings of your phone, USB Debugging is enabled.

Note: If you cannot find Developer Settings, just go to > Settings> About Phone> tap on Build Number for 7 times> then just go back to the settings and you'll see the Developer options.

And regarding the emulator, you might want to buff the resolution and the ram of the virtual device and try again.

Comment: I have been a mobile developer, never had these problems and i already know these common things to do, but i still have these problems